# Binary representation of a IP with inet_aton()

Tags: python, network-programming

When I use inet_aton() like this

```
packed_ip_addr = socket.inet_aton(ip_addr)
```

and print the value of packed IP:

```
print "Packed IP: %s" %packed_ip_addr
```

Nothing shown in the screen. How can I print the exact binary format of IP address?

Comment: `socket.inet_aton('127.0.0.1')` will return a `bytes`. What do you mean by nothing shown in the screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.format()` and `bytearray()`, you can have the binary representation of this IP: `192.168.1.2` like below:

**Both Python2 and Python3:**

```
import socket

a = socket.inet_aton("192.168.1.2")
b = bytearray(a)
# If you don't want to have '0b' at the final output:
# c = '{0:b}'.format(int(''.join(map(str, b))))
c = '0b{0:b}'.format(int(''.join(map(str, b))))
# print(c)
print c

>>> '0b1001001010011100110101100'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> ip = "192.168.137.39"
>>> print(bin(sum([int(k) * v for k, v in zip(ip.split("."), [1 << 24, 1 << 16, 1 << 8, 1])])))
0b11000000101010001000100100100111
```